# How to identify a colored string inside of an array?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2-D array I use as a map for a text based game I've written in Python.  I want to restrict users from walking on certain tiles.  This is an easy fix when it comes to the border, as it is represented with `'#'`'s along the edges.  However, in-game geography uses termcolor's colored module, e.g. mountains are `colored('^', 'red')`, which makes identifying the character kind of difficult.

```
if USERPOSITION == ('#' or -INSERT_COLORED_STRING-):  
    # revert to previous position.
```

When I simply type `'#' or colored('^', 'red')` , it identifies the normal pound symbol, but not the red `'^'`.  If I just put `'#' or '^'` I get the same results.

How can I have python check to see if a string is a colored character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional is wrong. You want to check if `USERPOSITION` is equal to `'#'` or if it is equal to `colored('^', 'red')`.

To do so, write out each condition explicitly and check if either is true using `or`:

`if USERPOSITION == '#' or USERPOSITION == colored('^', 'red'):`

Alternatively, you can use `USERPOSITION in ('#', colored('^', 'red'))`. This would be favorable if you had multiple different values of `USERPOSITION` that should match the condition.